# Ruminations on highly-scalable and modular distributed server side architectures

Tags: apache, architecture, amqp, thrift, twisted.web

Mine is not really a question, it's more of a call for opinions - and perhaps this isn't even the right place to post it. Nevertheless, the community here is very informed, and there's no harm in trying...

I was thinking about ways to create a highly scalable and, above all, highly modular back-end architecture. For example, an entire back-end ecosystem for a large site that had the potential for future-proof evolution into a massive site.

This would entail a very high degree of separation of concerns, to the extent that not only could (say) the underling DB be replaced (ie from Oracle to MySQL) but the actual *type* of database could be replaced (ed SQL to KV, or vice versa).

I envision a situation where each sub-system exposes its own API within the back-end ecosystem. In this way, the API could remain constant, whilst the implementation could change (even radically) over time.

The system must be heterogeneous in that it's not tied to a specific language. It must be able to accommodate modules or entire sub-systems using different languages.

It then occurred to me that what I was imagining was simply the architecture of the web itself.

So here is my discussion point: apart from the overhead of using (mainly) text-based protocols is there any overriding reason why a complex back-end architecture should not be implemented in the manner I describe, or is there some strong rationale I'm missing for using communication protocols such as Twisted, AMQP, Thrift, etc?

UPDATE: Following a comment from @meagar, I should perhaps reformulate the question: are the clear advantages of using a very simple, flexible and well-understood architecture (ie all functionality exposed as a series RESTful APIs) enough to compensate the obvious performance hit incurred when using this architecture in a back-end context?

Comment: Sounds like massive [inner-platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect). Why would you ever need this? What problem does this massively over-complex system solve? What does it provide that you can't get out of a traditional LAMP stack?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @meager. If anything I would say that it was the exact opposite of the inner platform effect. In other words, use the existing web architecture to manage the back-end too. That said, I've updated my question to take your comment into account.

Answer (score 0):

[code]the actual type of database could be replaced (ed SQL to KV, or vice versa).[/code]

And anyone who wrote a join between two tables will be sad. If you want the "ability" to switch to KV, then you should not expose an API richer than what KV can support.

The answer to your question depends on what it is you're trying to accomplish. You want to keep each module within reasonable reins. Use proper physical layering of code, use defined interfaces with side-effect contracts, use test cases for each success and failure case of each interface. That way, you can depend on things like "when user enters blah page, a user-blah fact is generated so that all registered fact listeners will be invoked." This allows you to extend the system without having direct calls from point A to point B, while still having some kind of control over widely disparate dependencies. (I hate code bases where you can't find-all to find *all* possible references to a symbol!)

However, the fact that we put lots of code and classes into a single system is because calling between systems is often very, very expensive. You want to think in terms of code modules making requests of each other where you can. The difference in timing between a function call and a REST call is something like one to a million (maybe you can get it as low as one to ten thousand, if you only count cycles, not wallclock time -- but I'm not so sure). Also, anything that goes on a wire in a datacenter may potentially suffer from packet loss, because there is no such thing as a 100% loss-free data center, no matter how hard you try. Packet loss means random latency spikes in the response time for your application.